# How to set the referer on a rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-referer, referer

I have the following problem: I use a script that saves the referer URL. I want this URL to one of my own URLs. So let's say a users access the page http://example.com/page1 I want to rewrite that URL to http://example.com/page2 and safe the referer on that page.

I don't want to do that with a PHP script as otherwise I would have to extend that script each time I want to track a new referer. I already tried these rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^page1$ /page2 [R=301,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^page1$ /page2 [L,R=301,QSA,NC]
```

The rewrite works, but the request parameter referer is missing. Do I have to use another stauts code than 301 or is there any other error in my rewrite. Is it even possible to set the referer in a rewrite rule?

Comment: It would be nice if the URL stays the same after the redirect but it is not neccessary.

Comment: I assume you mean referer header?  If that's the case, I don't think you can since mod_rewrite issues an external redirect to the browser.  Does the referer you get always say page1?

Comment: I indeed mean the HTTP_REFERER. I get no referer at all using page1 in the URL. Only using page2 in the URL I get the right referer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the *R* flag causes an external redirect. If you just want an internal rewrite, omit the *R* flag:

```
RewriteRule ^page1$ /page2 [QSA,NC]
```

Comment: But that wouldn't set the HTTP_REFERER or am I wrong? I want page1 to appear on page2 as the value of HTTP_REFERER. Is this even possible with a rewrite rule?

Comment: @Kau-Boy: Doing an internal rewrite doesn’t change the HTTP request. The request is just rewritten internally to another URI.

Comment: So in short, it is not possible without a PHP script in the middle that does a header redirect to change/set the HTTP_REFERER? When that's how I have to do it, it's all right. Just wanted to know if it works with rewrite rules. (If you add a "doesn't work that way to your answer, I'll accept it).

Comment: @Kau-Boy: The client sets that header field, not the server.

Comment: So the answer it: IT'S NOT POSSIBLE! Thanks for your answer making that clear!